# Trying to remove files from a super messy repository but they don't seem to be removed

Tags: git

So we've gone back to and old project to do some updates, now in the past no one has mentioned how messy the repository is. It's a very old one that's got many many commits and it seems it hasn't been very well managed.

Long story short the .git file is now 4.02Gb (yes that's right, Gb) in size. I'm trying to blast through and remove all of the old files that should never have been tracked in the first places (I can see some .ipa's and .swfs instantly that don't need to be there).

I've used a little shell script that atlassian recommend on their [Maintaining a Git Repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Maintaining+a+Git+Repository) which has listed out the top 10 offenders for me which is very helpful but I'm having a tough time removing the files from the history.

I've tried running `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file/dir>' HEAD` as everyone seems to suggest and then running a garbage collection. I've tried not to use an aggressive GC because it's so big that takes a few hours to run. However after running a gc with: `git gc --prune=now` it doesn't seem to be having any effect and the same files come up when I run my script to give me the list of biggest files.

What command(s) should I be using to remove a file previously committed from all of the history in my repository to help reduce the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing these two steps from [the Checklist for Shrinking a repository](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

> Remove the original refs backed up by git-filter-branch: say git
>   for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git
>   update-ref -d.
>
> Expire all reflogs with git reflog expire --expire=now --all.

Also, I would avoid `git gc --aggressive`  instead use

```
git repack -ad --depth=250 --window=250
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes you're right I was missing those few steps! I was running it originally on git for Windows but I've moved over to a linux machine as the `git for-each-ref` command wasn't working correctly with the pipe. However none of this seems to have solved the problem, the files still appear when running the big file locator script and the .git file size is not reduced at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the big file locator script only return blobs or does it give you a commit?

Comment: It's returning blobs, here's the main command it's running for reference: `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head` then it just iterates through displaying them on screen with the size, compressed size, sha and the objects location in the repository tree.

Comment: either your original filter branch missed it, or you have a reference to it still (branch, reflog, tag).

Comment: What would be the reason for my filter branch missing it? I've tried it probably 8-10 different times and tried it on some of the different big files that I don't want. I've removed all of the tags and all of the other branches so I just have a single local branch now called "master" and I've removed the origin (encase I mess up) so I would have thought it wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: Without knowing the path/name of the file and the exact filter branch command I can only speculate.  It could be as simple as your 'rm' command is just missing the correct argument to remove the file you want.

Comment: The exact command I was using was: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch ipad/iPad-test-app.ipa' HEAD` and the file path is ipad/iPad-test-app.ipa. This is what was being returned for me and it goes through saying that it's re-writing a bunch of the history. This is what has me most confused. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Can you verify that the script worked ok for at least one commit where that file was present?  For instance, if HEAD had that file, and you ran filter-branch, and now HEAD doesn't have that file.

Comment: Alright I think I figured it out. I'll make your answer as correct (as it was) but for future reference. It seems like cloning the repository after removing the unwanted files is the best approach. Making the references expire just wasn't working, not sure why but the repository is now below 1Gb. Thanks for your help Andrew C, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You re-wrote whichever branch you're currently on (HEAD). There could be other refs keeping the old commits alive - either other branches, or tags on the old commits.

And, of course, until you forcibly push your new copy of the branch, the old remote (eg. `origin/master`) will still be keeping those old commits alive.

Comment: I've removed all the other branches with `git branch -d <branch>`. There's just one Master now so I wouldn't have thought this would be the cause unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Is the "just one master" your local master? Is there still an 'origin/master', and have you pushed back to it? Are there definitely no tags?

Comment: Sorry, that was ambiguous. I'm doing a test run of removing all of the big files to ensure I don't screw anything up on the main repository since this is all destructive. I've taken the local copy I have and removed the remote, I've deleted all of the branches other than the master. There's no tags on the repository.

Comment: So `git show-ref` gives _only_ `refs/heads/master`?